# loop break with multi conditions step-by-step

Tags: ruby

I want to stop looping when one of my conditions is satisfied, but they are in sequences (step-by-step), and cannot be called all at one moment.

I need to check a condition, then use `next` to skip the loop. The code looks ugly with multiple conditions.

```rb
array.each do |x|
          new_varible_1 = condition_1 ? func1(x) : func2(x)
          next if check_condtion_1   
          new_varible_2 = condition_2 ? func3(new_variable_1) : func4(new_variable_1)
          next if check_condtion_2 ## check_conditon_x include new_variable assigned
          new_varible_3 = condition_3 ? func5(new_variable_2) : func6(new_variable_1)
          next if check_condtion_3
          ## etc
    end
```

I want to rewrite it more elegantly. Might it be programmable in dynamic approach?

> UPDATED: Thanks all for my newbie question but I have modified my example to describe my question better: Actually it requires assigns new variables in each step.  In case `check_condtion_` doesn't satisfy, i should skip the next step. Actually `condition_` and `function_` are very long step which make my code is very dumb

Comment: It surely does not make sense1

Comment: is it ruby at all?

Comment: Yeah the updated version is even more confusing than the original one. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to draw more good answers,
I think one way to do it is like this:

```
array.each do |x, condition_| ## each element is [x, true] 
  (condition_ = false; next) if 
      x.nil? || x.respond_to?("string") || x+y[x] == 4
end
```

Also there's no need of the `for`.

Answer (score 0):

@kimmo-letho answer is fine (the second part where the condition is actually modified.

I'd add a more idiomatic version, just for the sake of completeness, and because it's not easy to add code in comments.

```
array.each do |item|
  x, _ = item
  case
  when x.nil?
    item[1] = false
  when x.respond_to?("string")
    item[1] = 'it is a string'
  end
end
```

On the other hand, I have the impression that you are building the array of `[x, true]` by hand before the loop. If all you need is to print (or return) the items that have a true condition, you can do better:

```
# xs => [x1, x2, x3, ...]
# where your original array was [[x1, cond1], [x2, cond2], ...]
xs.reject do |x|
  x.nil? || x.respond_to?("string") || x+y[x] == 4
end
```

If you had already some false condition, and you want to keep the previous one:

```
# array => [[x1, cond1], [x2, cond2], ...]
array.map do |x, cond|
  [x, cond && !(x.nil? || x.respond_to?("string") || x+y[x] == 4)]
end
```